# Error con innerHTML y textContent

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

tengo la siguiente función para generar un contador, el codigo me funciona correctamente en la pagina en la pagina donde lo estoy utilizando, pero en otras paginas me da un error que esta buscando InnerHTML o una salida, pero no lo encuentra.
como podría modificar mi funcion para que no me de error en otras paginas? tampoco me funciona con textContent

```
        function contador(){
 
       let cont1 = document.getElementById('cont1');

       let cant1 = 20;



          let tiempo1 = setInterval(()=>{
           cont1.innerHTML = cant1 +=1;

           if(cant1=== 49){
         clearInterval(tiempo1)
            }

           },100);

           }
         contador();
```

HTML

```
       <div class="container">
       <div class="item" >
        
         <span class="cantidad" ' 
       id="cont1">0</span>
       </div>
     </div>
```

[image: Error en otras paginas]

- Resuelto *

  ```
    let cont1 = document.getElementById('cont1');
     if (cont1) {
    let cant1 = 20;

    let tiempo1 = setInterval(() => {
        cont1.innerHTML = cant1 += 1;

        if (cant1 === 49) {
            clearInterval(tiempo1)
        }

      }, 100);

      }
  ```

Comment: Cambia cont2 por cont1 en todas partes y asunto arreglado

Comment: perdon, copie otro html  que tenia, ahi lo arregle, pero ese no es el error, busca innerHTML donde no lo hay ?!

Comment: El código funciona bien... si en esta funciona y en otras no, es porque en las otras no existe un elemento `cont1`

Comment: claro, ese es el tema, quiero limitar a que solo se ejecute en una pagina, eso es lo que necesito modificar

Comment: entonces mete todo lo que hay debajo de `let cont1...` en un condicional `if(cond1) { ... aqui todo el código... }`. Asi, donde no exista `cond1`, pues no hace nada, asi no saca error.

Comment: Gracias bro, te pasaste!!!

Answer (score 1):

¿Por que no pruebas a poner el código del span en la misma línea?
También podrías poner-le el punto y coma después del clearInterval en la función contador

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="item" >
    
     <span class="cantidad" id="cont1">0</span>
   </div>
 </div>


 function contador(){

   let cont1 = document.getElementById('cont1');

   let cant1 = 20;



      let tiempo1 = setInterval(()=>{
       cont1.innerHTML = cant1 +=1;

       if(cant1=== 49){
     clearInterval(tiempo1);
        }

       },100);

       }
     contador();
```

Aquí también te falta el punto y coma después del clearinterval()

```
let cont1 = document.getElementById('cont1');
if (cont1) {
let cant1 = 20;

let tiempo1 = setInterval(() => {
  cont1.innerHTML = cant1 += 1;

  if (cant1 === 49) {
      clearInterval(tiempo1);
  }

}, 100);

}
```

Comment: El punto y coma no es siempre obligatorio en javascript y diría que en este caso no afecta para nada al funcionamiento de su código, tanto si lo pone como si no.

Comment: Gracias ya lo resolví, me faltaba agregar un if  para saber si existe la variable antes de usarla